# command line php uses values from apache2 php.ini file; why?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I am running PHP 7.4 from command line on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
It appears to use some config values from the "cli/php.ini" file as well as some values from "apache2/php.ini" file.
see expose_php and memory_limit values shown by "php -i" below:

```
admin@my-ubuntu-host:/$ lsb_release -a 2>/dev/null
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
admin@my-ubuntu-host:/$
admin@my-ubuntu-host:/$ sdiff -s ./etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini ./etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
disable_functions = pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcnt | disable_functions =
expose_php = Off                                              | expose_php = On
memory_limit = 256M                                           | memory_limit = -1
admin@my-ubuntu-host:/$
admin@my-ubuntu-host:/$ /usr/bin/php -i | egrep -i '(php version|expose_php|memory_limit|php.ini)'
PHP Version => 7.4.3
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php/7.4/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
PHP Version => 7.4.3
expose_php => On => On
memory_limit => 256M => 256M
admin@my-ubuntu-host:/$
admin@my-ubuntu-host:/$
```

How comes?

Comment: Do you have anything under php/7.4/cli/conf.d that could be setting the memory_limit?

Comment: @Mark: Indeed, there it is set to 256M too. **Thank you!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2791212/mark) for teaching me that .ini files in conf.d directory will overwrite the value set in php.ini.

Comment: No problem. So the general idea is that you leave php.ini alone so that any upgrades can use the maintainers version and any custom configuration you want is made under conf.d which are not overwritten during upgrade. If you make changes to php.ini and there is an upgrade you may get a prompt to say keep your version (which may now have outdated settings) or replace with the maintainers version.